# Why is only 1 query executed in this code involving scopes from the rails-jquery-autocomplete plugin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, scope

I"m looking at this code from the rails jquery autocomplete plugin.. in line 12 "items" is set to be a scoped object.  Then it seems over the next few lines that scoped object is reassigned several times.

When I run the code it seems only 1 query is being made wwhich is the sum total of all the scopes..(which is great, just not sure why). Does that mean that a scoped object accumulates scopes until the end of the method when it is executed?  Or does Active Record just optimize performance by minimizing the number of queries needed by waiting for all the queries to be gathered... help me understand :) :

```
def get_autocomplete_items(parameters)
    model   = parameters[:model]
    term    = parameters[:term]
    method  = parameters[:method]
    options = parameters[:options]
    scopes  = Array(options[:scopes])
    limit   = get_autocomplete_limit(options)
    order   = get_autocomplete_order(method, options, model)


    items = model.scoped

    scopes.each { |scope| items = items.send(scope) } unless scopes.empty?

    items = items.select(get_autocomplete_select_clause(model, method, options)) unless options[:full_model]
    items = items.where(get_autocomplete_where_clause(model, term, method, options)).
        limit(limit).order(order)
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's part of the niceness that Rails figures out for you, that when you're doing scopes of scopes of scopes (ad infinitum), that it Rails figures out how to make the query efficiently. There's a decent explanation [in this podcast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/108-named-scope) toward the end where Ryan shows the output of the scope queries.

Comment: Thanks man, I've found the term 'lazy loading' thrown around since I started looking.  Appreciate it.